# org-mode : how to calculate dynamic deadlines

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a scheduled start date of a task and the effort to complete the task in amount of days,

e.g in the case below N=5, start date is <2016-01-27 Wed>

How can the deadline be automatically calculated based upon scheduled_date+5days ?

such that in the end I have the following:

```
DEADLINE: <2016-02-03 Wed> SCHEDULED: <2016-01-27 Wed>
```

Comment: There are a few different methods for creating an entry creating a deadline and a scheduled timestamp.  Consider explaining how it is that you wish to create them so that there is a greater likelihood an answer will be forthcoming.  For example, you may wish to edit the post to include an `org-capture-template` entry; or, some other method you are contemplating using.  You may find that similar questions have already been asked and answered?:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10294/2287

Comment: The problem I have is that I already have some entries with predefined scheduled and deadline. However in some cases, due to some delays, some tasks' scheduled date need to be pushed to a later date. I'm trying to find an automated way to update the deadline dates of each entries automatically from the scheduled date + N days of effort.

Answer (score 4):

The following example calls `org-schedule`; the user inputs the date/time desired; then the timeshift of 5 days are added to the last inserted timestamp and that value is used programmatically by `org-deadline`.  If the user wishes hours/minutes to appear in the timestamp for the deadline, then set `with-hm` to `t`.

[Some additional work would be needed if the users wishes the deadline to have the exact same time of day as the scheduled date.  At the present time, the default is midnight for the deadline.]

```lisp
(defun schedule-me ()
(interactive)
  (org-schedule nil)
  (let* (
      (timeshift 5)
      (time
        (org-time-from-absolute
          (+
            timeshift
            (org-time-string-to-absolute org-last-inserted-timestamp))))
      (with-hm nil)
      (fmt (funcall (if with-hm 'cdr 'car) org-time-stamp-formats)) )
    (org-deadline nil (format-time-string fmt time))))
```